# 3rd party MySQL and Google Apps

Tags: mysql, mailing-list

I did scour the net and stackoverflow before posting this question, so forgive me if I overlooked anything already posted.

I admin a large amount of mailing lists through Google Apps.
At the moment we do this manually by "please add me to:" or "please remove me from:" emails.

I see no reason though to not do this through a php/mysql form and unsubscribe link.

My problem is that I have no idea how to communicate the mysql requests with google.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: google has something like mysql:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has something like mysql:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

I don't think you are going to be able to hook up to your own mysql from appengine.

You could put a rest api in front of your mysql server though.

Hope this helps